# custom input text label for play framework form

Tags: playframework-2.0

hi i have some problem with play framework forms

```
public class User extends Model{

    public String firstName;
    @Required
    public String lastName;
    @Required
    public String password;
    @Required
    public boolean bedAccess;

}
```

and i create a form in my template using Form helper

```
@form(routes.Application.createUser()) {
      <table border="1" class="inserTable">
      <tbody>
            <tr>
        <td>@inputText(userForm("firstName"))</td>
        <td>@inputText(userForm("lastName"))</td>
        <td>@inputPassword(userForm("password"))</td>
        <td>@checkbox(userForm("bedAcces"))</td> 
                <td><input type="submit" value="Create"> <td/>
                </tr>
           <tbody/>

<br/>
```

when i see the result my labels are printed the same as my User models fields like **firstName** but i want to have custom labels like "*users first name*" for my **firstName** field and "*user last name*" for my **lastName** field of my model what should i do?
and how ? 
any body can help?

Answer (score 22):

Pass the label parameter like:

```
@inputText(objForm("firstName"), '_label -> "You label")
```

Answer (score 1):

use can use @helper class for the initialize the view and pass the parameter like:

```
@(contacts: List[models.Contact])

  @helper.form(action = routes.Contacts.create) {

    @helper.inputText(form("name"), '_label -> "Name")
}
```